# .bat file autocopy - how to only copy file once?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, robocopy

I want a .bat file that will copy all files and folders from one folder to another folder automatically. For example:

```
robocopy "c:\source" "D:\target" /e /MON:1 /xc /xn /xo
```

However I need it so that once a file has been copied, that file will not be copied again, even if the copy has been moved to a different directory. Is there any way to do this? Is it possible for robocopy to create a log and check against that before copying the file?

If robocopy can't do it, what can?

Comment: Can you move the files in the source directory to another directory after the robocopy?  That way you're sure only new files get send to the target. Otherwhise you'd need more batch scripting to build a history list of files that already been send, or see if it can be done via a powershell script.

Comment: Might the archive-attribute help (robocopy option `/M`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use additionally the option `/M` on your [robocopy](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) (SS64 article) command line as suggested by [Stephan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152082/stephan) because this option results in copying only files with archive attribute set in source folder tree and removing archive attribute by **robocopy** after successful copying the file.

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe "C:\source" "D:\target" /M /E /MON:1 /XC /XN /XO
```

The archive attribute is automatically set again on file modification.

You could perhaps also use [xcopy](https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) (SS64 article):

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "C:\source" "D:\target\" /M /E /C /I /Q /G /H /R /K /Y >nul
```

Important for your task is again option `/M` for copying only files with archive attribute set in source folder tree and clearing the archive attribute after copying the file.

Note: `/I` works without user prompt only with target folder path ending with a backslash.

Run in a command prompt window `robocopy /?` respectively `xcopy /?` for details on the other options or read the Microsoft documentations for [robocopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) and [xcopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/xcopy).

Answer (score 0):

Alright So, the easiest way to do this is to copy each 
file and folder individually, to said folder.
This may not be what you are looking for, but 
I hope it helps! Sadly there is no way to 
copy l files folders with a single command.